# Why am I not getting a zero eigenvalue for my laplacian?

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
library(igraph)
el <- read.table("http://opsahl.co.uk/tnet/datasets/USpowergrid_n4941.txt")
g <- graph_from_data_frame(el)
gmat <- as_adjacency_matrix(g)
k <- degree(g)
D <- diag(k)
L <- D - gmat #find Laplacian
E <- eigen(L, T, only.values = T)
E$values
```

and when I run it, I don't get a zero eigenvalue for my Laplacian. I get the correct number of eigenvalues, but I don't have a zero. Can anyone tell me why that is?

Comment: Where is `gmat` defined? This example is not reproducible.

Comment: @MrFlick Oh I'm sorry, I missed that line. I've updated the code.